# Display variables values in a tkinter widget

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I am writing a program for interactive data fitting in python using Tkinter.
I would like to:

1. change the starting parameters (i.e. the guessing parameters) of the fitting curve manually form keyboard and plot the corresponding curve upon the experimental data in order to start the fitting procedure from a good point(ACHIEVED)
2. display the actual value of the parameters in a widget as I change them by keyboard (NOT ACHIEVED)

I've searched the net and I found some connections between my issue and Text widget or Entry widget..

Do anyone have a good solution?

here is the code modified as we're fitting a simple exponential, copy/paste run and try (use 'r','t','y','f','g','h' keys to modify params)..

```
import Tkinter as Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from numpy import *  #exp,arange,sin,arctan,where
import sys
from scipy.optimize import leastsq

class App:

def __init__(self, master,slave,folnam,q_index,tab):
    # Create containers
    self.frame = Tkinter.Frame(master)
    self.frame2 = Tkinter.Text(slave,width=10,height=10)
    self.frame2.pack()

    self.q_index=q_index

    # Create buttons and bindings
    self.button_quit = Tkinter.Button(self.frame,text="QUIT", command=master.destroy)
    self.button_quit.pack(side="left")
    self.button_fit = Tkinter.Button(self.frame, text= 'fit!')
    self.button_fit.pack()

    self.frame.bind_all("<Key>", self.decrease_a,'+')    #################################


    # Fill with Data
    self.t = arange(1000)*.001
    self.data_to_fit = exp(-self.t)
    self.A=max(self.data_to_fit)-min(self.data_to_fit)
    self.B=min(self.data_to_fit)

    # Build Figure
    fig = Figure()
    self.ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    self.ax.set_ylim( min(self.data_to_fit), max(self.data_to_fit) )      
    self.p = [self.A,self.B,.9,.5,10.,5.]
    self.line, = self.ax.plot(self.t[1:],abs(self.schultz(self.t[1:], 1., self.p)),'.-')   #tuple of a single element
    self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig,master=master)
    self.ax.plot(self.t[1:],self.data_to_fit[1:])
    self.canvas.show()
    self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)
    self.frame.pack()




def schultz(self, t, q, p):
    Z=.1
    A, B, alpha, D, vm, sigma = p
    Z = ((sigma/vm)**-2)-1.
    Lambda = q*vm*t/(Z+1)
    g = ((Z+1)/(Z*q*vm*t))*sin(Z*arctan(Lambda))/(1+Lambda**2)**(Z/2.)
    where( abs(t)>0., g, 1.)
    f = exp(-q**2*D*t)*((1.-alpha)+alpha*g)
    y = A*f+B
    return y




def decrease_a(self,event):

  # Raise/lower amplitude with 'a', 'q' keys
    if event.char=='a':
        self.ax.get_ylim()          
        self.p[0]-= 1e10
        self.line.set_ydata(self.schultz(self.t[1:], 1, self.p))
        self.line.set_xdata(self.t[1:])           
        self.canvas.draw()  
    if event.char=='q':
        self.ax.get_ylim()          
        self.p[0]+=1e10
        self.line.set_ydata(self.schultz(self.t[1:], 1, self.p))
        self.line.set_xdata(self.t[1:])           
        self.canvas.draw()  
    # Raise/lower baseline with 's', 'w' keys
    if event.char=='s':
        self.ax.get_ylim()          
        self.p[1]-= 1e10
        self.line.set_ydata(self.schultz(self.t[1:], 1, self.p))
        self.line.set_xdata(self.t[1:])           
        self.canvas.draw()      
    if event.char=='w':
        self.ax.get_ylim()          
        self.p[1]+= 1e10
        self.line.set_ydata(self.schultz(self.t[1:], 1, self.p))
        self.line.set_xdata(self.t[1:])           
        self.canvas.draw()
    # Raise/lower alpha with 'd', 'e' keys
    if event.char=='d':
        self.ax.get_ylim()          
        self.p[2]-= .05
        self.line.set_ydata(self.schultz(self.t[1:], 1, self.p))
        self.line.set_xdata(self.t[1:])           
        self.canvas.draw()
    if event.char=='e':
        self.ax.get_ylim()          
        self.p[2]+= .05
        self.line.set_ydata(self.schultz(self.t[1:], 1, self.p))
        self.line.set_xdata(self.t[1:])           
        self.canvas.draw()
    # Raise/lower diffusion coefficient with 'f', 'r' keys
    if event.char=='f':
        self.ax.get_ylim()          
        self.p[3]-= .05
        self.line.set_ydata(self.schultz(self.t[1:], 1, self.p))
        self.line.set_xdata(self.t[1:])           
        self.canvas.draw()
    if event.char=='r':
        self.ax.get_ylim()          
        self.p[3]+= .05
        self.line.set_ydata(self.schultz(self.t[1:], 1, self.p))
        self.line.set_xdata(self.t[1:])           
        self.canvas.draw()
    # Raise/lower average speed with 'g', 't' keys
    if event.char=='g':
        self.ax.get_ylim()          
        self.p[2]-= .05
        self.line.set_ydata(self.schultz(self.t[1:], 1, self.p))
        self.line.set_xdata(self.t[1:])           
        self.canvas.draw()

    if event.char=='t':
        self.ax.get_ylim()          
        self.p[2]+= .05
        self.line.set_ydata(self.schultz(self.t[1:], 1, self.p))
        self.line.set_xdata(self.t[1:])           
        self.canvas.draw()
    # Raise/lower variance of speed distribution with 'h', 'y' keys
    if event.char=='h':
        self.ax.get_ylim()          
        self.p[2]-= .01
        self.line.set_ydata(self.schultz(self.t[1:], 1, self.p))
        self.line.set_xdata(self.t[1:])           
        self.canvas.draw()
    if event.char=='y':
        self.ax.get_ylim()          
        self.p[2]+= .01
        self.line.set_ydata(self.schultz(self.t[1:], 1, self.p))
        self.line.set_xdata(self.t[1:])           
        self.canvas.draw()

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root2 = Tkinter.Tk()
app = App(root,root2,'/home/copo/Scrivania/correlazioni_da_fit',q_index=10, tab=False)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. When the type "from the keyboard", are they typing in the console, or are they typing in a text or entry widget?

Comment: @Bryan Oakley: you are right, I meant they're typing from keyboard while the focus is on the canvas widget that I use to plot curves; I would like the parameters to appear in ANOTHER widget (maybe a text one?or one with as many entries as the number of parameters?) while the focus remains in the canvas widget..thanks for the attention

Comment: Why must the focus be on the canvas? Why not just have the focus in a text widget or entry?

Comment: I'm posting the code editing my question, so it will be more clear

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but if all you're wanting to do is to display the values of `self.p`, you can do that in any number of ways. You could, for example, have a label that you update every time you change the parameter. For example:

```
self.p0_label = Tkinter.Label(...)
self.p1_label = Tkinter.Label(...)
...
def decrease_a(self,event):
    if event.char=='a':
        self.ax.get_ylim()          
        self.p[0]-= 1e10
        self.line.set_ydata(self.schultz(self.t[1:], 1, self.p))
        self.line.set_xdata(self.t[1:])           
        self.canvas.draw()  
    ...
    self.update_display()

def update_display(self):
    self.p0_label.configure(text=str(self.p[0]))
    self.p1_label.configure(text=str(self.p[1]))
    ...
```

Comment: Yes I need just to display the values of self.p in real time!Thank you very much!